# Next.js streaming route handler not expected

Tags: next.js, streaming

I'm new to Next.js and I am reading route handler , I wrote a code to test streaming , but request seems to not receive a stream response from route handler api but receive all chunks:

First , I create a route handler in `/app/api/stream/route.js`:

```js
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

function sleep(second){
    return new Response((res,rej) => {
        setTimeout(res,[second])
    })
}

const encoder = new TextEncoder();
async function* iterator(){
    yield encoder.encode("<p>One</p>");
    await sleep(5000);
    yield encoder.encode("<p>Two</p>");
    await sleep(5000);
    yield encoder.encode("<p>Three</p>");
}

function iteratorToStream(iterator){
    return new ReadableStream({
        async pull(controller){
            const {value,done} = await iterator.next();
            if(done){
                console.log("Done")
                controller.close();
            }
            else{
                console.log("Enqueue Data: " , value)
                controller.enqueue(value);
            }
        }
    })
}

export async function GET(request){
    const headerList = headers();
    console.log("HeaderList: " , headerList);
    const stream = iteratorToStream(iterator());
    return new Response(stream);
}
```

Second , I create a server component in `/app/fetchStreamExample/page.js`:

```js
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";
import { useState } from "react";

export const metadata = {
    title: "I am boy"
}

export const runtime = "edge";

async function* iterator(reader){
    while(true){
        const {value,done} = await reader.read();
        if(done){
            console.log("已結束 ...")
            return "";
        }
        console.log("讀取資料: " , value);
        yield value;
    }
}

// Readable Stream Demo
const decoder = new TextDecoder();
export default async function FetchStream(){
    const data = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/stream");
    // console.log("Data: " , data);
    // data.body.getReader().read().then(({value,done}) => console.log("結果: " ,  decoder.decode(value)));
    const reader = data.body.getReader();
    for await(const result of iterator(reader)){
        console.log("結果: " , decoder.decode(result));
    }
    return <></>
}
```

Finally , I type "`npm run build`" to build next.js project to vercel and type "`npm run start`" to  request http://localhost:3000/fetchStreamExample in browser , but it got `"結果: <p>One</p><p>Two</p><p>Three</p>"` in the console.

Could anyone tell me what's going wrong ?

I expect that there is this output in the console :

```
結果: <p>One</p>
結果: <p>Two</p>
結果: <p>Three</p>
```

but it came out like this:

```
結果: <p>One</p><p>Two</p><p>Three</p>
```